# Device Registration to Azure Notification Hubs

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to use Azure Notification Hubs for remote notifications for my mobile app.

When my mobile app is first installed on a device, I create and store an `installationId` on the device which is a `GUID` value. I use [Shiny](https://shinylib.net/) to handle device registration with Apple/FCM and then it gives me a `registrationToken`. I then pass both my `installationId` and `registrationToken` along with device platform to my backend API where I use the code below to handle the registration:

```
public async Task RegisterDevice(Guid installationId, string registrationToken, string platform)
{
   var installation = new Installation();
   installation.InstallationId = installationId.ToString();
   installation.PushChannel = registrationToken; // This is the registration token I get from Shiny
   installation.Platform = platform == "ios" ? NotificationPlatform.Apns : NotificationPlatform.Fcm;

   await _notificationHubsClient.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation);
}
```

The `_notificationHubsClient` is my wrapper for `NotificationHubClient` that comes with the `Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs` NuGet package.

WHen I check the registration info by getting all the registrations on my notifications hub, I don't see my `InstallationId` anywhere in the `JSON` object. Instead I see the `registrationToken` as `InstallationId` under `tags`. It looks like this:

```
{
    "eTag": "1",
    "expirationTime": "9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999Z",
    "registrationId": "1234567890232290733-3250316115430032296-3",
    "tags": [
      "$InstallationId:{999a99a9999999a99a99a9a99aa99999}" // <- This is the registrationToken value
    ],
    "pushVariables": null,
    "pnsHandle": "aAaaBCdeF0qUgk7kMPrVUB...",
    "isReadOnly": false,
    "extensionData": {}
  }
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Good news, you're not doing anything wrong. If you retrieve the Installation using the [Read Installation operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/read-installation), your installation ID and tokens will match the format you were expecting here.

Azure Notification Hubs has two *mostly* separate ways to store device records, Installations and Registrations. Mostly, the distinction was a way to allow for API changes without introducing backwards compatibility questions. For example, changing policy on what happens when a device handle expires, moving to an asynchronous model, etc. For better or worse, Read All Registrations was decided to return all devices stored a hub, not just records that were added as registrations. While that does allow for a unified way to get all records, it does cause a little confusion.